# error while starting another activity

Tags: android

i am starting new activity from current activity but some how before starting activity i am getting Null Pointer exception. and startActivity() from source activity calls sucessfully. I am getting Null Pointer exception. the following is code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PdfFileSelectActivity.this, PdfViewerActivity.class)
        .putExtra(EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, pdffilename)
        .putExtra(EXTRA_USENIO, useNIO);
```

i checked intenet pdffilename variable and they are not null. and the following is declaration in manifest file.

Hope to hear soon.

Comment: please post more of the error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved via skype session - the problem was that the intent extras were read outside the onCreate, where the boolean useBIO was declared as class variable - but at that point the intent extras are not available yet.

```
boolean useNIO = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(PdfFileSelectActivity.EXTRA_USENIO, PdfFileSelectActivity.DEFAULTUSENIO);
```

had to be moved inside onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

you must specify the name of both the activity in androidmanifest.xml file
eg:

```
`<activity android:name=".PdfFileSelectActivity"/>
```

this activity is already defined in .xml file but you have also to define this activity

```
<activity android:name=".PdfViewerActivity"/>
```

after

```
<application/> tag`
```

Comment: hello abhinav i tried that but that is also not working it is giving that exception. the following is exception.

Comment: hello abhinav i tried that but that is also not working it is giving that exception. the following is exception.    Java.lang.RunTimeException Unable to Intiate Component Info.